# how can access the value of variable in setOnCheckedChangeListener listener from onclick

Tags: java, android, variables

I want to access value of gender variable  from `onClick(View v)`.

value of gender produce in `onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int selectedId)`
and I dont know how can access this value

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
package com.dietandroidproject;

import Databasedata.Person;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final RadioGroup genderselected = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.selectgender);

    genderselected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int selectedId) {
            selectedId=genderselected.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton genderchoosed = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            gender = genderchoosed.getText().toString();

        }
    });
    Button saveinformation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveinformation);
    saveinformation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        EditText weighttext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weighttext);
        EditText heighttext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.heighttext);
        EditText usernametext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernametext);
        EditText agetext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agetext);
        //RadioGroup genderselected = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.selectgender);
        Spinner activitytext = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.chooseactivity);
        Button saveinformation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveinformation);
        //TextView genderchoosed = (TextView) findViewById(genderselected
                //.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        //String gender = genderchoosed.getText().toString();
        String pa = activitytext.getSelectedItem().toString();




        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int weight = (int) Float.parseFloat(weighttext.getText()
                    .toString());
            float height =  Float.parseFloat(heighttext.getText()
                    .toString());
            String username = usernametext.getText().toString();
            int age = (int) Float.parseFloat(agetext.getText().toString());
            String pa = activitytext.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //BMI======================================================
            int Bmivalue = calculateBMI(weight, height);

            String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(Bmivalue);
            float idealweight = idealweight(weight, height, gender, pa, age);
            double dailycalories=dailycalories(weight,height,gender,pa,age);
            //DB insert====================================================
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setUsername(username);
            person.setHeight(height);
            person.setWeight(weight);
            person.setAge(age);
            person.setGender(gender);
            person.setPa(pa);
            person.setBmivalue(Bmivalue);
            person.setBmiInterpretation(bmiInterpretation);
            person.setIdealweight(idealweight);
            person.setDailycalories(dailycalories);
                            Databasedata.DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter = new Databasedata.DatabaseAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this);
            dbAdapter.insertPerson(person);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    Bmivalue + "and you are" + bmiInterpretation,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    }
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundmain"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/personinformation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.98" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/heighttext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usernametext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usernametext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Your Height" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernametext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weighttext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/heighttext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heighttext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Your Weight" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/agetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weighttext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weighttext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Your Age" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#aaa" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/choosegender"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.78" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choosefemaleormale"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Gender : "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#555"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/selectgender"
        android:layout_width="220dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/choosefemaleormale"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/femaleselected"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="female"

             />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/maleselected"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="male"
             />
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
    <View
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#aaa" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/choosepa"
    android:layout_width="250dip"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/chooseactivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/activityitems"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:prompt="@string/level_of_activity" />

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.46"
    android:background="@drawable/recent_foods_depressed"
    android:hint="save"
    android:text="save"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:onClick="saveinformation"
    android:id="@+id/saveinformation"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I need value of gender in `float idealweight = idealweight(weight, height, gender, pa, age);` and also `double dailycalories=dailycalories(weight,height,gender,pa,age);`

can any one help me?

Comment: You have serious flaw in your code, initialize your EditText & buttons outside on click.

Comment: @VenomVendor I am new to Android development so I have flaw in my code as u said. I  initialized my edittext and button out of onclick right now,thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String sex = null;
...

onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int selectedId){
  if(selectedId == R.id.femaleselected){
     sex = "female";
  } else {
     sex = "male";
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: because I want to access value of 'gender variable' from my functions which onclick(view) call them.I wrote what u said but no answer.

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps:

add member String mGender to your activity.

```
MainActivity extend ...
String mGender = null;
onCreate ...
```

replace the gender by mGender and everything should work

```
onClick(View v) {
if(mGender != null){
// use mGender

// float gender = Float.valueOf(mGender);
//double gender = Double.valueOf(mGender);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't get exactly what u mean!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 genderselected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int selectedId) 
       {
            switch(selectedId)
           {
            case R.id. femaleselected:
                Log.d("","female selected");
            break;
            case R.id. maleselected:
                Log.d("","male selected");
            break;
        }

        }
    });
```